# Joi | Validation Error message is printed with unexpcted characters

Tags: javascript, typescript, joi

We started to use Joi ("version": "17.4.2") for our type validation.
I wish to use Joi's error message property and display it to our users but Unfortunately the message is coming back to the user in the following way:

> "{\n  "password": "mypass123",\n  [41m"username"[0m[31m [1]: -- missing --[0m\n}\n[31m\n[1] "username" is required[0m"

expected:

> "username" is required

there is not much to see at the code sample:
(BadRequestError receiving a string, and working well)

```
if (isValidationError(error))
{
    return new BadRequestError(error.message);
}
```

my schema:

```
    export const workGroupValidationSchema = Joi.object({
    username: Joi.string().required(),
    password: Joi.string().required(),
});
```

My guess is that for some reason it try to render a message for console and not as a simple string, any ideas?